# 404 error from a render component

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When using {% render "Bundle:Controller:Action" %} that returns a:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error - 404');
```

It successfully causes the page to error in development mode, but in Production mode the page renders except for the {% render %} part where now it is just blank.

I'd like the entire page to display a 404 page, just like if the exception was thrown in the parent action.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring back errors instead of just silently failing you simply need to add the ignore_errors option after the with object.

e.g.

```
{% render 'Bundle:Controller:Action' with { }, { 'ignore_errors' : false } %}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It successfully causes the page to error in development mode, but in
>   Production mode the page renders except for the {% render %} part
>   where now it is just blank.

This seems legit. You use

```
{% render "Bundle:Controller:Action" %}
```

to render only a part of your webpage, e.g. a menu. If the specific render action throws a 404 it affects only this part of the website but not the entire page.

---

Besides, why should the entire page, which obviously renders well, be blocked by a 404 error page that effects only a part of the page? This is not good practice. If the error has great importance then you should trigger it on a higher instance, on controller level.

Comment: I'd like it to throw a 404 for the entire page.

Comment: 404 Errors should not be thrown on View layer. They should only be thrown at Controller layer. You should probably rethink your Design of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is a CMS environment and therefore different things are rendered in depending on the person's choice. Therefore the 404 needs to be thrown from inside the rendered action. And they are thrown from inside the controller of the rendered action.

Comment: I would expect to be able to tap into some sort of event and do it that way.

Comment: Simply redirect the whole request away from this action to your error page.

Comment: You can also render any template within a Controller and catch, handle and throw exceptions there. This should be done since the Controller keeps the logic of processing incomming requests. And since I read from you that the rendered template depends on the 'person's choice' the view layer is still the wrong place to do that kind of stuff. Rethink it and render the correct template in the Controller and do exception handling there and nowhere else.

Comment: Errors are being thrown by a controller. I just want the errors not be be enclosed in this rendered view, and instead be in the parent view. In development the Exception is successfully shown (Symfony error page with debug). I want to replicate this in production.